# SQL Server - Multiple foreign key constraint in one go

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am very much use to work with ORM (e.g. EF, L2S). So, finding difficulty writing queries.

I've created an `Employee` table also few masters like `Department`, `Area`.

Schema is something like:

- `Employee` (`Id, Name, DeptId, AreaId, ManagerId`)
- `Area` (`Id, Name`)
- `Department` (`Id, Name`)

Now, I want to add constraint in ONE GO.

Something like,

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT] FOREIGN KEY (DEPTID) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(ID)
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT] FOREIGN KEY (AREAID) REFERENCES AREA(ID)
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_EMPLOYEE_EMPLOYEE] FOREIGN KEY (MANAGERID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(ID) --Self Reference
```

but, I know this is syntax error.

So, please correct my script to enable me to do this. I don't want add constraint one by one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The spec shows that you need to add a comma after each `ADD CONSTRAINT` line

Comment: Yes.it is like that. I am not aware about syntax very much. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT] 
               FOREIGN KEY (DEPTID) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(ID),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT] 
               FOREIGN KEY (AREAID) REFERENCES AREA(ID),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_EMPLOYEE_EMPLOYEE] 
               FOREIGN KEY (MANAGERID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(ID)
```

Comment: Yes, That i know but, Is it possible in one ALTER TABLE statement?

Comment: The question is how NOT to do that. Besides, `GO` is not a valid T-SQL command

Comment: @DipalMehta try the above

Answer (score 1):

You just need to separate each constraint with a comma, eg:

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE 
  ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT] FOREIGN KEY (DEPTID) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(ID),
      CONSTRAINT [FK_EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT] FOREIGN KEY (AREAID) REFERENCES AREA(ID),
      CONSTRAINT [FK_EMPLOYEE_EMPLOYEE] FOREIGN KEY (MANAGERID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(ID)
```

You can find the syntax of the ALTER TABLE statement in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) and in Books Online

Answer (score 0):

works with comma. Your query was perfect.

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT] FOREIGN KEY (DEPTID) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(ID),
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT] FOREIGN KEY (AREAID) REFERENCES AREA(ID),
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_EMPLOYEE_EMPLOYEE] FOREIGN KEY (MANAGERID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(ID)
```